# Create administration area in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm creating a blog with Rails and the first thing that I've done is the administration area (by now is the only thing I have in the application). I've used Bootstrap to quickly design all the pages and Devise for authentication.

For all the models, views and controllers I used `scaffolding` and I generated both `Admin` and `Post` models.

The problem is that now I have to create the REAL blog and access the administration panel using `/admin` route. For example, to create a new post I should access `http:/mysite/admin/posts/new`.

Another problem is that I will have a totally different design in the public blog page (not Bootstrap) and of course I'll have different controllers, views and routes.

So, what can be done?

Answer (score 15):

I would suggest removing the `Admin` model as in your case it seems more like a namespace than a model. I would instead create an `:admin` namespace in your `routes.rb` file like:

```
namespace :admin do
   resources :posts
end
```

This will cause all routes inside of this block to be prefixed w/ `admin`. So the URL for editing a post on the admin side would be `admin/posts/:id/edit`.

Next I would suggest making an `AdminController` that all of your admin controllers will inherit from. This way you can specify a new layout. Then you can create a `Admin::PostsController` at `app/controllers/admin/posts_controller.rb`

**app/controllers/admin_controller.rb**

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  layout 'admin'
end
```

**app/controllers/admin/posts_controller.rb**

```
class Admin::PostsController < AdminController
  def index
    # admin/posts
  end
end
```

**app/views/admin/posts/index.html.erb**

```
Hello from the admin/posts view!
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the blog page should be public, that means non authentication is needed to view it. For the rest you are already using devise to protect that area.

For the different template is quite easy, you could create 2 layout and set the desired layout in the controllers.